# A problem on eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $P_A(x)$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Let $A \in GL_3(\mathbb R)$. Suppose $P_A(x) = P_{A^2}(x)$. Then what are the possible values of the sum of the roots (trace of $A$) of $P_A(x)$?

Through examples, I get $0$ is a possibility when $A$ has a complex root ( because $1+w+w^2 = 0$). Similarly, the identity matrix has trace $3$. Are these the only possibilities? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The eigenvalues of $A^2$ are exactly the squares of eigenvalues of $A$. So, the eigenvalues (with multiplicity) form a multiset $S$ for which $x\mapsto x^2$ permutes $S$. In particular, for any complex eigenvalue $x$, $x^2$ must also be an eigenvalue, so it must be the conjugate of $x$. Can you use this to narrow down the possibilities for the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: 1 or primitive cube root of unity?

Comment: @GA316 Yep, exactly (zero would also be another option, if the matrix weren't required to be invertible).

Answer (score 1):

These are matrices that have roots: $\{0,0,0\}$ (this is not necessarily a zero matrix), $\{0,0,1\}$, $\{0,1,1\}$, $\{1,1,1\}$ (this is not necessarily an identity matrix), $\{0,\omega,\omega^2\}$, and $\{1,\omega,\omega^2\}$, where $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$.

It is not hard to show that there are no others.

Thus, all possible values of traces are: $0, 1, 2, 3, -1$.

Comment: Why can $0$ be an eigenvalue? $A$ is nonsingular.

Comment: I considered all matrices of order three. For traces of nonsingular matrices, there are only two possibilities: $0$ and $3$. Thank you for your comment.